# Inserting multiples values into text file from user input

Tags: c++

I have this project where I need to insert multiples integers into text file by taking user input with certain range of that input in loop

```
void append_text_multiple() {
    std::string file_name;
    std::cin >> file_name;
        
    std::ofstream getfile;
    getfile.open(("C:\\users\\USER\\Documents\\located_file\\" + file_name+ ".txt").c_str());
        
    std::string verify_dtype;
    std::cin >> verify_dtype;
    
    if(verify_dtype == "int" || "INT") {    
        int total_line;
        int item_append;
        std::cin >> total_line;
        for(int j=0; j<=total_line; j++) {
            std::cin >> item_append;
            getfile << item_append << '\n\';
            getfile.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Now that when I inserted 1 2 3 4 5 as my input while being inside the loop the output of that text file returns only single value which is 1 while I was expecting for 1
2
3
4
5. I'm not sure what's going on?

Comment: You may consider using array.

Comment: @CPP_is_no_STANDARD Please provide your solution on answer, I'm not sure how to implement your idea into code.

Comment: What is `getschema` and why do you close it at the end of each iteration of the `for` loop ?

Comment: Please provide a code without error.

Comment: Assuming `getschema` is actualy `getfile`, you should close it only after dumping all the values into it (i.e. after the `for` loop completes).

Comment: Another issue: if you need `total_line` values, the loop should be `for(int j=0; j<total_line; j++)`  (`<` instead of `<=`).

Comment: Side note: this operator (`verify_dtype == "int" || "INT"`) does something different from what you meant.

Comment: Thanks you all for pointing out the `getfile` swapped with `getschema` I made a mistake while writing the question.

Comment: @CPP_is_no_STANDARD do you mean to use an array for storing all the values, and then write them to the file from the array ? If so - why is it needed in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are several issues in your code:**

1. Your `for` loop does `total_line+1` iterations, instead of `total_line`. The loop should be `for(int j=0; j<total_line; j++)` (`<` instead of `<=`).
2. You close the output file immediatly after writing the first value. Therefore the later writes are not performed. You should close it after all the values are written.
3. Your condition for checking the value of `verify_dtype` is wrong, assuming you wanted to check whether the varaible has either 1 of the 2 values.

**Fixed version:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

void append_text_multiple() {
    std::string file_name;
    std::cin >> file_name;

    std::ofstream getfile;
    getfile.open(("C:\\users\\USER\\Documents\\located_file\\" + file_name + ".txt").c_str());

    std::string verify_dtype;
    std::cin >> verify_dtype;
    
    if ((verify_dtype == "int") || (verify_dtype == "INT")) {
        int total_line;
        int item_append;
        std::cin >> total_line;
        for (int j = 0; j < total_line; j++) {
            std::cin >> item_append;
            getfile << item_append << "\n";
        }
        getfile.close();
    }
}

int main() {
    append_text_multiple();
}
```